# MySQL query check two value in one column

Tags: mysql

I am writing one query where I have 4 types in column

```
Xtype
-----
P
C
D
R
```

I want to check where `Xtype=P` and `Xtype=D` so how can I use both for the same column? I know I can use for different column using `WHERE id=1 AND status=online` but not sure how to check two value for the same column

Comment: what will be the result if it exist? if it does not exist? can yu give the desired result? i'm sure you have other columns other than that.

Comment: So xtype can only be of one type lets say P or D but no PD is that correct?

Comment: @Ateszki of course value will be only one for the row. But I want to check any of them two.

Comment: @pixelngrain can you tell us what your output look like if ever all values exist in your condition or not all conditions met?

Comment: @JW. thanks for your feedback, got an answer exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I am having media upload system and for content I have Xtype so currently I am using only one Xtype P but I realize that I might require some more type to allow user to upload media

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WHERE .. IN` like this:

```
WHERE XType IN ('P','D')    -- checks whether the  Xtype is P or D
```

Which incidentally gets expanded into OR:

```
WHERE (XType = 'P' OR Xtype = 'D')
```

If you want to check whether that column contains records for both 'P' and 'D' then you could use a EXISTS & sub-query:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableName WHERE Xtype = 'P') 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableName WHERE Xtype = 'D')
```

Comment: he wants to check the existence of both value.

Comment: oh yeh this is nice way to do using `IN` that's how I can allow use to add multiple Xtype from setting panel. right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish. The IN (..) gets compiled behind the scenes to a a set of conditions ORed together.

Comment: @JW. I don't want to check both value, I am sorry but something misunderstood my question. I want to check any of two exists

Comment: @MikyDinescu your answer is perfect what I was looking for. What I was saying that if I have setting panel which allow user/admin to choose what Xtype he wants than using `WHERE Xtype IN($variable)` I can allow them to add any of these four types so they can change in case if needed.

Comment: @pixelngrain - yes, you could do that provided that the $variable expands to a comma separated list of values. But you should try to use prepared statements with query parameters instead of directly injecting variable into your SQL queries. This practice helps defend against SQL injection attacks! But if you use prepared statements you will not be able to have variable number of parameters in your query..

Comment: Oh I see. any possibility to get some reference code. would be appreciated. else no worry try to find on google :) thanks a lot to you and everyone for great help

Answer (score 1):

See Miky D., apart from that you can simply use `WHERE Xtype= 'P' OR Xtype = 'D'`, no magic behind this.

Comment: he wants to check the existence of both value.

Comment: You may be right but I think it's not really clear what he wants. As far as I understand it it is either P or D.

Comment: I agree with you. The question  lacks enough detail.

Comment: @cara yes you have understand correctly and I was looking either P or D. I am sorry JW for confusion.